# Why only few SQL Server Extended event plan handle 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

We have created an extended event to capture long running queries , the objective is to get execution plan by joining on plan handle column
some event data has a plan handle with id value however some has just has"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" - which is a problem for me and unable to fetch execution plan based on this ZERO and produce Null.

here is 1 sample , please guide what is wrong here and how to retrieve execution plan for such Plan handle ?

Many thanks for your time.

```
<event name="sql_batch_completed" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2022-08-19T16:13:10.711Z">
  <data name="cpu_time">
    <value>34797000</value>
  </data>
  <data name="duration">
    <value>42259048</value>
  </data>
  <data name="physical_reads">
    <value>640</value>
  </data>
  <data name="logical_reads">
    <value>17204111</value>
  </data>
  <data name="writes">
    <value>79477</value>
  </data>
  <data name="row_count">
    <value>8180</value>
  </data>
  <data name="result">
    <value>0</value>
    <text>OK</text>
  </data>
  <data name="batch_text">
    <value>select  SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS [Current_System_DateTime_Offset],  event_data,  
  DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [ServerDateTime] 
   , (select top 1 query_plan from sys.dm_exec_query_plan(CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), '0x' + 
   CAST((CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value(N'(event/action[@name="plan_handle"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'))  AS varchar(4000)),1))) Query_plan  ,
   CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value(N'(event/action[@name="plan_handle"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') plan_handle
   
 FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\folder1\long_queries_long_queries_36c0ad49cf4e462fb7419312d0*xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) 
 where  DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) &gt;  '2022-08-18 17:45:11.3280000'
  order by DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) desc</value>
  </data>
  <action name="collect_system_time" package="package0">
    <value>2022-08-19T16:13:10.711Z</value>
  </action>
  <action name="client_app_name" package="sqlserver">
    <value>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query</value>
  </action>
  <action name="client_hostname" package="sqlserver">
    <value>CHANDAN-PC</value>
  </action>
  <action name="database_name" package="sqlserver">
    <value>SQLPlanner</value>
  </action>
  <action name="plan_handle" package="sqlserver">
    <value>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</value>
  </action>
  <action name="session_id" package="sqlserver">
    <value>53</value>
  </action>
  <action name="session_nt_username" package="sqlserver">
    <value>CHANDAN-PC\Chandan Kumar</value>
  </action>
  <action name="sql_text" package="sqlserver">
    <value>select  SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS [Current_System_DateTime_Offset],  event_data,  
  DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [ServerDateTime] 
   , (select top 1 query_plan from sys.dm_exec_query_plan(CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), '0x' + 
   CAST((CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value(N'(event/action[@name="plan_handle"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'))  AS varchar(4000)),1))) Query_plan  ,
   CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value(N'(event/action[@name="plan_handle"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') plan_handle
   
 FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\folder1\long_queries_36c0ad49cf4e462fb7419312d0*xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) 
 where  DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) &gt;  '2022-08-18 17:45:11.3280000'
  order by DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CONVERT(XML, event_Data).value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) desc</value>
  </action>
  <action name="transaction_id" package="sqlserver">
    <value>0</value>
  </action>
  <action name="transaction_sequence" package="sqlserver">
    <value>0</value>
  </action>
  <action name="username" package="sqlserver">
    <value>CHANDAN-PC\Chandan Kumar</value>
  </action>
</event>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP has `sql_batch_completed` as the event and an added Action to collect the  plan handle:

```
<event name="sql_batch_completed" package="sqlserver" [...]

<action name="plan_handle" package="sqlserver">
```

Actions can be executed but it doesn't mean they will produce anything helpful. In this case, a batch does not have an execution plan (a single statement batch could but that's not the semantics).

For example, I can create a session on lease expiry for an availability group and add an action to grab the plan handle, but there will be no plan handle, still the action will occur and no meaningful data will be collected.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Unhelpful] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.availability_group_lease_expired(
    ACTION(sqlserver.plan_handle))
```

You'll want to monitor the individual statements as they will have a plan associated with them... however that will also cause significant overhead to the system.

What you're attempting to do is already done for you, for the most part, with [query store or QD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16)S. Leveraging that will be much more beneficial and less overhead than XEs.